# sweet tea spontaneous fermantation

Tags: fermentation, tea

I got a half-gallon jug of sweet tea from Bonjangle's months ago.
Didn't drink it, but kept it in my fridge for about 3 months. The plastic jug was bloated when I came to realize it.
I knew it wasn't too ideal but felt adventurous, so I tried it. tasted pretty good, kind of like mead.

I had not added any yeast or anything into it.

Is it super bad that I tried something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Usually not. If the fermentation was aerobic it is usually OK if it tastes good enough to drink. If the fermentation was anaerobic the fermentation is usually good if carried out in suitably acidic conditions - to prevent C.Botulinum developing. Anaerobic but not acidic conditions can be the source of pathgenic organisms or their toxins.